# Array filtering with jq on sub level

Tags: json, jq

All the demo/examples I saw are filtering on the *first* level, but I want to do the array filtering with jq on the second level:

```
{
  "TheArray": [
    {
      "F1": "V11",
      "F2": "V12",
      "F3": "V13"
    },      
    {       
      "F1": "V21",
      "F2": "V22",
      "F3": "V33"
    }  ]
}
```

I want to filter with `"F1" == "V11"`, and get:

```
{
  "TheArray": [
    {
      "F1": "V11",
      "F2": "V12",
      "F3": "V13"
    }  ]
}
```

Is that possible with `jq`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would be suitable if you want a solution that simply "edits" the original document, retaining any other keys that the top-level object might have:

```
.TheArray |= map(select(.F1=="V11"))
```

### Variations

```
with_entries( .value |= map(select(.F1 == "V11")))
```

Another:

```
del(.TheArray[] | select(.F1!="V11"))
```

And if you have a more recent version of jq than version 1.5:

```
.TheArray[] |= select(.F1=="V11")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this jq filter:

```
jq '.TheArray |= map(select(.F1=="V11"))' file
```

`select` command choose the right element and `map` is building the array based on the selected elements.